# How can I create a list of .aspx pages?

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu, filesystems

I need to create a Drop Down List in a Web User Control (.NET 4.0, C#, Web Forms).

This list should be the list of .aspx in the folder MyPages, into my web application.

How can I create it? I need to read folder->files or there are a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("/MyPages"));
FileInfo[] fileinfo = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.aspx");

// do data binding here
```